# Question about a proof in Graham and Lehrer's "Cellular algebras"

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

I'm sorry if this question is too basic for MO. I'm reading [a paper by Graham and Lehrer "Cellular algebras"](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002113384) and have trouble understanding one step in a proof of a crucial theorem. I suppose that the problem is probably quite easy, but for some reason I got totally stuck.

It is proposition 3.2 (ii) on page 11: Let $(\Lambda, M,C,\ast)$ be a cell datum for a cellular algebra $A$, $\lambda \in \Lambda$,$rad(\lambda) = \{ x \in W(\lambda) | \phi_\lambda (x,y) = 0 \ \forall y \in W(\lambda) \}$. Then if $\phi_\lambda \ne 0$, the quotient $W(\lambda) / rad(\lambda)$ is (absolutely) irreducible.

It is shown in the course of the proof that $W(\lambda) = Az$ for some $z \notin rad(\lambda)$. Then it says "it follows that $W(\lambda) / rad(\lambda)$ is irreducible".

Can someone explain why this implication holds?

Comment: Usually it's best to raise such a question first at Stack Exchange (or perhaps email the senior author). It's also helpful to include an online link: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002113384.   Probably the magic formula "It follows that ..." is concealing use of some details developed in Section 2.   The paper is formal and has lots of steps, but it has been highly influential in further study of various classes of algebras.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: I thought exactly these kinds of questions qualify as "research level mathematics" and are encouraged on MO... Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I think questions like this are fine at MO, but I totally second Jim's point about links being needed.

Comment: @Johannes, darij: I don't intend to be dismissive about the question itself, but the axiomatic background is quite complicated and needs to be well understood to decipher proofs (for instance, the notion of "rad").  Like many research papers, the wording of proofs here is not always optimal, but Section 2 does need to be well assimilated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $W(\lambda)=Az$ for all $z\notin rad(\lambda)$, then $rad(\lambda)$ is a maximal submodule of $W(\lambda)$ (in fact it follows that it is the *unique* maximal submodule and therefore it is equal to the module-theoretic radical of $W(\lambda)$). In particular $W(\lambda)/rad(\lambda)$ is irreducible. It follows from Corollary 2.6 that it is absolutely irreducible.

Comment: Thank you! The crucial word here is the quantifier in "all $z\notin rad(\lambda)$...". Then it's pretty obvious. My problem was that I was reading more along the lines "for some fixed $z$" rather than "all $z$".